# MVVM communicate between views

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I know we can use the Mediator Pattern to communicate between view models but what about views?

Lets assume I have a button in View A which should trigger functionality of View B. How is this preferably done? I could use the Mediator but it seems more like a hack.

Here is a thought of mine:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Lets assume I have a button in View A which should trigger functionality of View B.

According to the MV(V)C Pattern there should not by any "functionality" in any View.

The functionality should be in the *controller* layer which handles the applications state by altering the *model* as needed.

Now you can have as many view layers (in parallel or sequentially) viewing the model data and manipulating them via the controller.

Since the *model* provides infrastructure to propagate changes the View B can register for certain Properties to get change information so that it can update itself when View A changed that property.

---

> So for functionality I have extra classes called (some prefix)ViewController? Do we also have controller for viewmodels? (ViewModelController) – Asperger

Do not put your fath on that names. 
After all names are just dust in the wind.

The point is that you have to deal with this 3 layers *model*, *controller*, and *view*. The different names (MVC,MVVC, MCP) are only variation and don't mean that much to me.

You also do not necessarily put them into separate projects, packages or classes. The pattern is basically about the *direction of communication*:

- the *model* does never talk to anything else directly, only via interfaces it provides itself (mainly *getter/setter* methods and `*Listener` interfaces).
- the *controller* only talks to the *model* via the *models* interfaces.
- the view gets data (and change information) to display from the *model* and translates user input to calls in the *controller* layer. It never updates the *model* itself.

Comment: So for functionality I have extra classes called (some prefix)ViewController? Do we also have controller for viewmodels? (ViewModelController)

Comment: I think in this case it would be called MVVMC

Comment: @Asperger Your views do not need to communicate at all... if they do, they are no longer views! Views only contain the layout of the UI. Any communication or coordination needs to be done through the controller.

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer so is it correct to say that my interceptor is actually the controller that acts as a messenger between my lets say viewmodels? Viewmodels arent directly part of the view so that should be fine.

Comment: Your views should not be communicating at all.
If you went on a tour of an art museum, would you expect the paintings (the views) to be talking to each other or you? The tour guide (the controller) would be the one communicating with you, and bringing you to different exhibits.

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer unfortunalely your allegory is not fully matching. In our projects we want to be able to Exchange the *view* without changing the (knowledge of) the controller. If the exhibition changes the paintings the guide has to learn them...

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer here is how your *gallery* example would match: The paintings are the *model*, the guide is the *controller* and the visitors are the *view*. The visitors will never touch the paintings themselves but will ask the guide about details, and they may scan the newspaper for new paintings being shown.  The guide may rearrange the paintings if enough visitors complain to have a poor view i them...